# Put Wordpress blog in a virtual directory of an other MVC site

Tags: azure

I have two "Standard" web sites on Azure where one is a Wordpress blog:

```
http://foo.com 
http://blog.foo.com
```

Is there any way to make the blog a virtual directory of the website so the url to the blog becomes:

```
http://foo.com/blog
```

UPDATE:

I'm hoping this is possible:

[image]

But what to enter as ???

/Niels

Answer (score 0):

Log with a FTP client like Filezilla and create your "blogg" directory under the **site/wwwroot** folder and then enter **blogg** as the physical path.